# Counting down lives in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a simple python turtle game where the turtle needs to make it to the circle, while avoiding the moving square. I would like the code to count down lives and move the turtle back to the beginning until there are 0 lives left. The code below allows for one play and then the motion loop does not repeat.

I have tried a recursive function (move(3)), but then the onkey commands don't work....

```
import turtle, random, time

#background
canvas = turtle.Screen()
canvas.bgcolor('black')

#Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.penup()
pen.color('white')
pen.hideturtle()
pen.penup()

#Lilypad
pad = turtle.Turtle()
pad.hideturtle()
pad.color('yellow')
pad.shape('circle')
pad.penup()
pad.setposition(0,290)
pad.showturtle()

#Turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.hideturtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('green')
player.penup()
player.left(90)
player.setposition(0, -290)
player.showturtle()

#truck
truck1 = turtle.Turtle()
truck1.hideturtle()
truck1.shape('square')
truck1.color('blue')
truck1.penup()
truck1.showturtle()

speed = random.randint(1,5)

def move():
  #move player and truck
  player.forward(2)
  truck1.forward(speed)
  if truck1.xcor() > 300 or truck1.xcor() < -300:
    truck1.right(180)

 #win if hit the lilypad
  if player.distance(pad)<10:
    pen.penup()
    pen.setposition(0,-50)
    pen.write('You win!', align='left', font=('Arial', 36, 'normal'))
    done()

  #lose a life if hit the truck
  if player.distance(truck1) < 30:
    player.setposition(0,-290)
    life = life - 1
    while life > 0:
      pen.penup()
      pen.setposition(0,-60)
      pen.write('Try again', align='left', font=('Arial', 36, 'normal'))
      time.sleep(1)
      pen.clear()
      move()

    #game over if 0 lives left
    pen.penup()
    pen.setposition(0,-60)
    pen.write('Game over!', align='left', font=('Arial', 36, 'normal'))
    done()

  canvas.ontimer(move,10)

canvas.onkey(lambda:player.setheading(90),'Up')
canvas.onkey(lambda:player.setheading(180),'Left')
canvas.onkey(lambda:player.setheading(0),'Right')
canvas.onkey(lambda:player.setheading(270),'Down')
canvas.listen()

life = 3
move()
canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: to repeat something you can use loop - `for` or `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this is to move *all* your initialization code into a function, which invokes your `move()` function as it's last step.  The first thing that the initialization code does is call `canvas.clear()` which pretty much wipes out everything.  Then your `move()` function makes a choice at the end whether to call itself on the next timer iteration, or call the initialize code on the next timer iteration to reset everything and start a new game.

Below is your code reworked along the above lines as well as various teaks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint
from time import sleep

FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'normal')

def initialize():
    global pen, pad, player, truck, speed, life

    canvas.clear()  # assume that this resets *everything*
    # background
    canvas.bgcolor('black')

    # Pen
    pen = Turtle(visible=False)
    pen.color('white')
    pen.penup()

    # Lilypad
    pad = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    pad.color('yellow')
    pad.penup()
    pad.setposition(0, 290)
    pad.showturtle()

    # Turtle
    player = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
    player.color('green')
    player.penup()
    player.setheading(90)
    player.setposition(0, -290)
    player.showturtle()

    # truck
    truck = Turtle('square', visible=False)
    truck.color('blue')
    truck.penup()
    truck.showturtle()

    speed = randint(1, 5)

    canvas.onkey(lambda: player.setheading(90), 'Up')
    canvas.onkey(lambda: player.setheading(180), 'Left')
    canvas.onkey(lambda: player.setheading(0), 'Right')
    canvas.onkey(lambda: player.setheading(270), 'Down')
    canvas.listen()

    life = 3

    move()

def move():
    global life

    # move player and truck
    player.forward(2)

    truck.forward(speed)
    if not -300 < truck.xcor() < 300:
        truck.right(180)

    # lose a life if hit the truck
    if player.distance(truck) < 20:
        player.setposition(0, -290)
        life -= 1

        if life > 0:
            pen.setposition(0, -60)
            pen.write('Try again', font=FONT)
            sleep(1)
            pen.clear()

    # win if hit the lilypad
    if player.distance(pad) < 20:
        pen.setposition(0, -50)
        pen.write('You win!', font=FONT)
        canvas.ontimer(initialize, 1000)
    elif life == 0:  # game over if 0 lives left
        pen.setposition(0, -60)
        pen.write('Game over!', font=FONT)
        canvas.ontimer(initialize, 1000)
    else:
        canvas.ontimer(move, 10)

canvas = Screen()

pen = None
pad = None
player = None
truck = None
speed = -1
life = -1

initialize()

canvas.mainloop()
```

This should let you play over again whether you win or run out of lives.